# An issue in plotting the quantum circuit using latex

Tags: programming, qiskit, quantum-circuit

Here's the code I'm working on:

```
!pip install pylatexenc
!pip install pillow

qc = QuantumCircuit(2)
qc.x(0)
qc.cz(0,1)
qc.x(0)
qc.draw('latex')
```

However there's an error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'pdflatex': 'pdflatex'
```

What should I do to make it work? Thanks!!

Comment: Did you try to restart the kernel once the installations were done? Usually in Jupiter Notebook it does the trick :)

Comment: @ Thanks for the comment! Yes I did:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you forgot to install a $\LaTeX$ processor.

To solve the issue, install any $\LaTeX$ distribution. Below are the two main ones that can be installed both on Windows and Linux:

- https://www.tug.org/texlive/
- https://miktex.org/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to output the circuit in latex format, you can set the `output = 'latex'` within the `draw` function of Qiskit.

For instance, suppose I want to plot the following circuit in latex:

```
           ░       ░      
q_0: ──■───░───■───░───■──
     ┌─┴─┐ ░ ┌─┴─┐ ░ ┌─┴─┐
q_1: ┤ X ├─░─┤ X ├─░─┤ X ├
     └───┘ ░ └───┘ ░ └───┘
c: 2/═════════════════════
```

I can do it as follows:

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit,QuantumRegister
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
qreg_q = QuantumRegister(2, 'q')
creg_c = ClassicalRegister(2, 'c')
circ = QuantumCircuit(qreg_q, creg_c)
circ.cx(0,1)
circ.barrier(range(2))
circ.cx(0,1)
circ.barrier(range(2))
circ.cx(0,1)
circ.draw( style={'name': 'bw'}, output = 'latex', plot_barriers= True, initial_state = True, scale = 1)
```

The output would be:

[image]

---

You can look into [this documentation here](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.visualization.circuit_drawer.html) for more detail.